# Response Cookie not updating after first time being set

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a cookie helper class that gets and sets data for a cookie.

In my controller action I'm trying to update a List collection and persist that to the cookie.

*UPDATE:* It seems using HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add() even if the cookie exists or not it will do an upsert on it and work correctly. 
So what's the purpose of Reponse.Cookie.Set() then?

```
private List<int> _TestNumbers = new List<int>();
cookie = new CookieHelper(_searchCookieName);
cookie.SetData("testNumbers", _TestNumbers);

_TestNumbers.Add(1);
cookie.SetData("testNumbers", _TestNumbers);
_TestNumbers.Add(2);
cookie.SetData("testNumbers", _TestNumbers);
_TestNumbers.Add(3);
cookie.SetData("testNumbers", _TestNumbers);
```

The cookie helper class

```
public class CookieHelper
{
    public CookieHelper(string cookieName = null, HttpContext context = null)
    {
        // Set param defaults
        context = context ?? HttpContext.Current;

        if (cookieName != null)
            _cookieName = cookieName;

        // Load cookie if it exists, if not create one.
        _cookie = context.Request.Cookies[_cookieName] ?? new HttpCookie(_cookieName);

        Save();
    }

    public object GetData(string name)
    {
        return _cookie[name] == null ? null : new Base64Serializer().Deserialize(_cookie[name]);
    }

    public void SetData(string name, object value)
    {
        _cookie[name] = new Base64Serializer().Serialize(value);
        Save();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(_cookieExpiration);

        // Create the cookie if it doesn't exist
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(_cookieName) == null)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(_cookie);
        else
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(_cookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Base64Serializer implementation are you using ? I did not find a Framework class by a quick search. So maybe there is an error in the serializer concerning lists ?

Comment: @robe It's just a wrapper I made for the BinaryFormatter and Convert.ToBase64String/Convert.FromBase64String calls. I've tested that It does serialize and deserialize correctly.